# I do not understand why it comes up with a syntax error

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am making a program in c++ class and I do not understand why this syntax error is a semicolon is not defined. If you need me to send stacktrace then, I will put it up in the comment section. I have multiple errors in this H class. I am new programmer in c++. Thank you for your contribution.

```
#pragma once
#ifndef CONVERT_M_TO_FT_H
#define Convert_M_to_Ft


class Convert_M_to_Ft {
private:
    double feet, meters, inches, centimeters;
    const double METERS_PER_FOOT;
    const double INCHES_PER_FOOT;
public:
    Convert_M_to_Ft();
    void conversion();
    void setFeetAndInches(double feet, double inches);
    double getMeters();
    double getCentimeters();
};
#endif
```

Comment: `#define Convert_M_to_Ft` ----> `#define CONVERT_M_TO_FT_H`. The way you set it up has `Convert_M_to_Ft` expand to an empty token sequence. Your class has not name.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
#define Convert_M_to_Ft
```

with

```
#define CONVERT_M_TO_FT_H
```

---

The problem is that the preprocessor expands

```
class Convert_M_to_Ft {
private:
   //...
};
```

to

```
class {
private:
   //...
};
```

otherwise.

Comment: are u kidding me.

Comment: @jdog1218 _"are u kidding me"_ Huh?? Certainly not. That's exactly what happens with your code. What#s the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you:

```
#define Convert_M_to_Ft
```

That means that `Convert_M_to_Ft` will be converted to nothing in your code. Specifically this line:

```
public:
    Convert_M_to_Ft();
```

Will be converted into:

```
public:
    ();
```

And that's probably where your syntax error is coming from. You should include the actual error with actual line numbers if that's not the only error.

You probably meant to do this on the top:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef CONVERT_M_TO_FT_H
#define CONVERT_M_TO_FT_H
```